# Swift - pass the same parameter from one function to the other

Tags: ios, function, parameters, swift2, parameter-passing

I have two functions in swift 2 code.

```
func myfunctionA (sender: UIButton!){

// some code

myfunctionB (sender: UIButton!) }
```

The other function is func myfunctionB. 
I call myfunctionB from inside of myfunctionA.

I need to know how to pass the same sender parameter from myfunctionA to myfunctionB.

Comment: Could you please let me know why this question is down voted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func myfunctionA (sender: UIButton!){
  myfunctionB(sender);
}
```

should work

Comment: Thanks. Actually it was myfunctionB(sender). The ; was not needed.